# Tell company that I went to interview but interviewer did not respect start time

Tags: interviewing

I had an interview for a position in Company A, with the manager. He was interested and said I was going to have a second interview with Company B manager.

I would be hired by Company A and to work for them, but under management of Company B (they manage software development process).

I was going to have the second interview today at 16:00. I went there 15:35.
The interviewer was in a meeting, and he told me to wait. I waited until 16:30 and then said them I was leaving, since I had to be elsewhere by 17:20.

Would it be rude to inform Company A manager about this? I fear the interviewer will say Company A that I didn't go to the interview in revenge for not waiting.

Comment: Would have been a good idea to tell them early that you had to be elsewhere at 17:20, and not at 16:30.

Comment: So if the interview get well and last more than 30 min what would you do

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza: presumably the interview was supposed to be an hour interview, starting at 4, by the time the OP left, it was half over. Regardless of how wise it was to make the two appointments back to back, the 4 O'clock appointment was a bust.

Comment: Both you and the manager behaved badly. You behaved badly by agreeing to an interview when you didn't have enough time to do an interview. The manager behaved badly by agreeing to interview you and then not making it a priority to show up for your interview. What is there for anyone else to say about this situation?

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I do want another interview, but since Company A is the hiring one, maybe I have to ask them and tell why

Comment: If I were the interviewer or manager in either Company A or B, I'd be left with the impression that you weren't particularly interested in this job. Your resume would be off my desk & in the bin.

Comment: @brhans justbecause you are offering a job means that I must wait for you when we already agreed a starting time? that's total disrespect, no matter if you are the one with "money", using your position of power to make clear to the employee that "he is not important" is not something I would do if I am the employer. I was and I am interested in the job, that's why I went 25 min earlier and waited for 1 hour sit there.

Comment: It's really unclear what result you're expecting to achieve from this course of action. You're not going to get the job without an interview with Co. B, and you've now probably made a bad impression there. Arguing with some random people on the other side of the internet doesn't get you anywhere. And the simple fact that you're here asking this question appears to indicate that you're aware of the situation - they have something you want (the job) and there are other candidates applying. Unless you're offering them something rare or unique, then in all likelihood you've messed up...

Comment: If they are so disrespectful of your time when both parties need to give a good impression (interviews are two-way roads!), imagine how little they would care about you when employed. Would you want to work for them after such a display?

Comment: Why would an interviewer from a company ask you to attend an interview with an interviewer in another company? Is there any relation between the two companies?

Comment: @WaisKamal as I stated, I interviewed with the "owner" or final client of the app. Then with the owner of the company that manages their software development process (the first was "outsourcing" the software development but also they were using their own employees under management of the latter company)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

> I was going to have the second interview today at 16:00. I went there 15:35.

This is your first mistake. It is fine to get to an interview early, but *wait* somewhere other than in the bosses office.

It's inconvenient for an interviewer to have to change their plans. Get there early, but wait until 5-10 minutes before the interview before talking to the company.

A practical reason is perhaps what you just experienced. If you arrive only a bit before your interview the interviewer will get a ping/call/IM from the front desk saying, "Candidate is here" and then you can leave nearly immediately to go meet the candidate and begin the interview.

If you show up 25 min early, this ping happens *way* too early for Manager B and it's entirely possible to forget about the interview or get caught into a conversation and *forgot* you were going to interview. You are then relying on another ping to the manager in order for them to definitely remember.

> I waited until 16:30 and then said them I was leaving, since I had to be elsewhere by 17:20.

A few things here. First, always plan on an interview going long-ish unless you have a defined end time from the company. If your interview had gone until 17:00 from 16:00 when it was supposed to be, would this have worked out for you?

Second, don't just get there 25 minutes early, wait, and then leave another hour later.

The way this should work:

- Arrive 5-10 minutes early
- Talk to someone
- 10 minutes after interview was supposed to start, at latest, ask someone for an update and get a time you should hear from them

  - Followup again at that time
- If it's 30 minutes later and you need to leave, tell them that you have an appointment that requires you to leave by X

  - **Also figure out next steps at this point**. It's possible something blew up and Manager B just couldn't get away. Who knows. But figure out what the next steps are at *this* point in the process, to avoid super awkward followup questions

If this is such an important thing for you (early interview ending) make sure to figure this out ahead of time with the company in your correspondence.

> Would it be rude to inform Company A manager about this? I fear the interviewer will say Company A that I didn't go to the interview in revenge for not waiting.

It's nearly never a good idea to badmouth a previous employer in an interview and most certainly not a good idea to do so to your potential future employer.

What you could do is touch base with Manager A a few days after you hear back from Manager B (or HR, or whatever) and ask. Hopefully you got contact information or had "next steps" from them when you walked out.

Comment: I am curious about the downvote? Further explanation would help make this answer better.

Comment: So, should I wait to hear from the interviewer about next steps? I already emailed him with an apology for what happened, and told him that "I went early with hope to start the interview at the agreed time". And asked him about what he wants to do next. I must make clear that he is not part of the company I will be working for, bur his company will act somewhat like a team leader for Company A project.

Comment: "hired by Company A ... but under management of Company B" How well this will work depends on the quality and honesty of both managers. What you should do now is carefully consider what the Company A manager tells you that the Company B interviewer says about you and the missed interview. If it's dishonest or unfair, or heavily shaded to paint you in a bad light, you have an early warning about what working for these two bosses will be like.

Comment: I don't understand the bias against arriving early.  If I arrive early, I understand cooling my heels until the agreed time, but if you depended on me arriving 5-10 minutes early (and no earlier) to "ping you" then you are probably not excited about me and why should I waste any time on you.  Why can't your electronic calendar system "ping you"?

Comment: If I was that early I would probably make myself known and find somewhere discreet to wait out of the way until everyone is ready. Also, it's not the candidate's job to "remind" the interviewer so they don't "forget" about the interview - that's just silly.

Comment: I don't see anyone mentioned this yet, to my surprise, so I will do: It is unacceptable to let candidate wait for 30 minutes after the scheduled start time. Obviously.

Answer (score 5):

Would have been a good idea to tell them early that you had to be elsewhere at 17:20, and not at 16:30.

The interviewer was in some meeting which started before the interview time and ran over the scheduled time. He had the choice of cutting that meeting short, or make you wait. Assuming that you would wait, he continued with the meeting.

If you had said early that you had to go somewhere else, he could have changed this and done your interview first. So it may be your own fault that the interview didn't happen.

Comment: I have told recruiters that I needed to leave at a certain time, only to have my request ignored. I had to cut the interview short and did not get the job. In general, I would say that whenever possible, you should clear your schedule for the rest of the day.

Comment: From their point if view, if you haven't planned for the possibility that the interview may go long, you probably aren't interested enough in the job. They may be right; it may run long because they like you and want more people to talk to you. Plan accordingly; reschedule something if necessary.

Comment: This does not answer the question though.

Comment: Why would the interviewer assume you would wait? Do you also expect the interviewer to wait when you arrive 30 minutes late for an interview, or is that a double standard?

Answer (score 0):

As several others have pointed out, with your first interview, it is generally poor etiquette to arrive more than 10 to 15 minutes early, likewise it is unwise to make assumptions on how long the interview will last.

The fact you had a second interview elsewhere scheduled just 90 minutes after the first interview may well raise a question mark on your ability to plan ahead.

That said, if you still want to interview with the first company, you should make contact as quickly as possible. You will need to apologise for being unable to wait, confidently ask for when he would like to hold the rearranged interview - and then cross your fingers

Comment: Just because he has another meeting scheduled doesn't mean it's another interview, not that it's important.

Answer (score 0):

You should inform the A person that you had shown up for the interview and waited but was unable to be seen during the time that it was scheduled, and that you had to leave. Thank them for the interview opportunity and if there is a way you can reschedule with B.

On a side note, a little over 1 hour for an interview (especially in a tech position) may not be enough time. I've spent 2-4 hours in an interview before. However they should have given you a rough time frame that the interview would last, if they told you that it would only be 1 hour long, then having plans 1 1/2 hours later would be acceptable.

The company was also wrong, they have an interview block and they should stick with it. If they have an emergency come up, Mr. B should have come out and apologize and reschedule with you at the time of the interview. It's very unprofessional to have you wait.

Comment: Exactly right.  No mention of disrespect, just the facts, he was there, they couldn’t see him at that time, want to reschedule.